# Parsing DateTime C# not working for my format

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to parse this date into DateTime `"26 July 2015 - 17:57:37"`.
The problem is that I have tried different formats on it but it is still not working.

```
string[] formats = { "dd MMM yyy - hh:mm:ss"};

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(DateofLecture, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           DateTimeStyles.None, out TempDateTime))
{
     Lecture.DateAndTime = TempDateTime;
}
```

I searched it on internet and applied all relevent formats but it never worked.

Comment: What is actually happening?

Comment: @Liero Still not working

Comment: @JamieRees it is not getting into if, it does not return true

Comment: @Charlie what do you mean "not working"; do you get an exception, does it crash, what happens?

Comment: What is the result of the `TempDateTime` var?

Comment: @Nikola.Lukovic No no exception,  it was just not returning true.

Answer (score 7):

You have three problems - with months, years and hours.

```
string[] formats = { "dd MMMM yyyy - HH:mm:ss"};
```

Comment: `+1` for the first fully correct answer. Also I don't think there is an array needed since there is only one format :) Just using string overload would be better :)

Answer (score 5):

You need to use

- [`yyyy` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#yyyySpecifier) instead of `yyy` for full year part.
- [`MMMM` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#MMMM_Specifier) instead of `MMM` for full month name.
- [`HH` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#HH_Specifier) instead of `hh` for [24-hour clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock) format.

---

```
string DateofLecture = "26 July 2015 - 17:57:37";
DateTime TempDateTime;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(DateofLecture, "dd MMMM yyyy - HH:mm:ss", 
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out TempDateTime))
{
    Lecture.DateAndTime = TempDateTime;
}
```

Comment: @GSerg Yeah, fixed other parts as well.

Comment: @Charlie Glad to help.